# how to prevent privilege escalation by changing HTTP response values?

Tags: httpresponse, penetration-testing, websecurity

i want to know how to mitigate privilege escalation by changing the response values,

for example in response body: isAdmin=false

change it to

isAdmin=true

and get the privilege

Comment: The client can do whatever it wants with the response. Privilege escalation is when the client can do privileged things on the server. If your server doesn't just accept `isAdmin` as the truth, then this isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Any user (client) supplied arguments must be sanitized in order to protect application from unintentional behavior by design. Generally frameworks forks well for generic vulnerabilities.

All sensitive data such as `isAdmin` attributes must be stored securely, so only server-side application can manipulate that data. Server-side stored sessions are mostly used to achieve that, but client side session storage in form of encrypted blob can be used by the "secure session storage" implementation (see python flask/werkzeug framework for examples).

Answer (score 0):

Payload is always changing based on the client or if its a client tool(Postman), you can send the payload you want. So the sensitive information, like if an user is an Admin or not should not be stored with client. It should be stored in the database against a user information. So the client can send only user details and backend will verify whether the user has certain roles or not.